# Recalculate TCP checksum

Tags: c

I'm writing a userspace application for DDoS mitigation and to implement certain mitigation policies I need to be able to change TCP options and things like sequence and acknowledgement numbers in packet headers on the fly.

The usual way to calculate the checksum would be to recreate a new TCP pseudoheader and iterate over the entire data packet to calculate the checksum but there is another way which involves just calculating the differences between only the words changed and doing a ones-complement subtraction.

My current code seems to be off frequently by 1 or 2. I suspect this is a problem because I'm not handling carries/borrows correctly. I have very little idea on how I would go about fixing this:

```
unsigned short pseq1, pseq2, pseq3, pseq4
unsigned short sum1, sum2, sum3, prevcheck;
short pdiff1, pdiff2;

u_char *pkt_data;

prevcheck = (pkt_data[50] << 8) | pkt_data[51];

pseq1 = (pkt_data[38] << 8) | pkt_data[39]; 
pseq2 = (pkt_data[40] << 8) | pkt_data[41];

pkt_data[38] = ((seq_num - offsetResult) >> 24) & 0xFF;
pkt_data[39] = ((seq_num - offsetResult) >> 16) & 0xFF; 
pkt_data[40] = ((seq_num - offsetResult) >> 8) & 0xFF;
pkt_data[41] = (seq_num - offsetResult) & 0xFF;

pseq3 = (pkt_data[38] << 8) | pkt_data[39];
pseq4 = (pkt_data[40] << 8) | pkt_data[41];

pdiff1 = pseq1 - pseq3;

pdiff2 = pseq2 - pseq4;

sum1 = ~pdiff1 + ~pdiff2;

sum2 = ~sum1;

sum3 = sum2 + prevcheck; 

pkt_data[50] = (sum3 >> 8) & 0xFF; 
pkt_data[51] = sum3 & 0xFF;
```

In this instance: `68 05 ca 57 94 05 60 73 5c d0 57 bf 08 00 45 00 00 2c 00 00 40 00 3f 06 bc a5 b9 aa 2a 6a 42 f9 58 19 00 50 ed 48 fc e4 57 e5 6e c0 f6 c8 60 12 72 10 fe f3 00 00 02 04 05 b4 00 00`

The produced checksum is `fef3` when it should be `fef2`.

Any suggestions would be amazing!

Comment: Please show the declarations of the variables and the definition of their types as well.

Comment: @Acorn: I've gone ahead and added the variable declarations with their type definitions. Everything we are working with is unsigned and, for the most part, short.

Comment: @rustyx: I do need to worry about carries during arithmetic with values that "wrap-around" if I'm not mistaken. I definitely would likely some clarity as it's definitely not consistent.

Comment: @rustyx: I declared pdiff as a signed short and removed the -1 and +1 if statements and my checksum values are still frequently incorrect by 1.

In this instance: `68 05 ca 57 94 05 60 73 5c d0 57 bf 08 00 45 00 00 2c 00 00 40 00 3f 06 bc a5 b9 aa 2a 6a 42 f9 58 19 00 50 ed 48 fc e4 57 e5 6e c0 f6 c8 60 12 72 10 fe f3 00 00 02 04 05 b4 00 00`


The resulting checksum is `fef3` when it should be `fef2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
u_int32_t sum;
u_int16_t oldSeq1, oldSeq2, newSeq1, newSeq2;
u_int16_t oldChecksum;

sum = ~oldChecksum - oldSeq1 - oldSeq2;

sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);

sum = sum + newSeq1 + newSeq2;

sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);

sum = (u_int16_t)~sum;
```

As my requirement was only to edit either sequence or acknowledge sequence numbers the above code was the solution for me using suggestions from all. This will account for all carries as the fold is done after each arithmetic operation instead of at the end where it could skew results.

This will work equally for changes in the IP header or TCP header as long as you pad anything shorter than 16 bits to 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 1071](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071), the checksum is calculated using a 16-bit 1's complement sum.

> On a 2's complement machine, the 1's complement sum must be
> computed by means of an "end around carry", i.e., any overflows
> from the most significant bits are added into the least
> significant bits.

So you should "reverse" the "end around carry" when updating the checksum.

I.e. subtract 1 for each negative carry and add 1 for each positive carry.

Something like this:

```
int32_t sum; // or just int, but make sure it's 32-bit or more
unsigned short pseq1, pseq2, pseq3, pseq4
unsigned short prevcheck;

u_char *pkt_data;

prevcheck = (pkt_data[50] << 8) | pkt_data[51];

pseq1 = (pkt_data[38] << 8) | pkt_data[39]; 
pseq2 = (pkt_data[40] << 8) | pkt_data[41];

pkt_data[38] = ((seq_num - offsetResult) >> 24) & 0xFF;
pkt_data[39] = ((seq_num - offsetResult) >> 16) & 0xFF; 
pkt_data[40] = ((seq_num - offsetResult) >> 8) & 0xFF;
pkt_data[41] = (seq_num - offsetResult) & 0xFF;

pseq3 = (pkt_data[38] << 8) | pkt_data[39];
pseq4 = (pkt_data[40] << 8) | pkt_data[41];

sum = ~prevcheck - pseq1 - pseq2;

while (sum >> 16)
    sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16); // "end around carry"

sum += pseq3 + pseq4;

while (sum >> 16)
    sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16); // "end around carry"

sum3 = (short)~sum;

pkt_data[50] = (sum3 >> 8) & 0xFF; 
pkt_data[51] = sum3 & 0xFF;
```

Comment: After some testing I believe this works very well :)

Comment: Upon further testing it seems like your fold does not take into account negative carries, only positive.

Comment: I was able to use your code to make a working solution. The fold must be done after the two subtractions and after the two additions separately to account for the resulting positive and negative carries afterward.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP checksums use 1's complement arithmetic, which is similar to 2's complement plus carry feedback. I.e. if you add two 16bit values, and get a carry, you need to add 1 to the sum.

Your code uses unsigned 16bit integers (BTW, I recommend using [fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer), instead of `int` and `short`, when the size matters, as in this case), so when adding them the carry is lost.

A better way is to use 32bit variables for the intermediate result, then feeding back the carry. For example:

`uint16_t a, b;
...
uint32_t sum = (uint32_t)a + (uint32_t)b;
if (sum > 0x10000u) {
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
}`